# How to find a linear combination of vectors that is congruent to $0\pmod 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

My goal is to find a linear combination of the following vectors such that the result is $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) \pmod 2$. I've been trying to find a calculator to do it, but even Wolfram Alpha says it's too big of a matrix to reduce. In order to find the coefficients $a_i$ such that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...a_{12}v_{12}\equiv (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\pmod 2$, my textbook says something about setting up a $12$ by $12$ identity matrix $I$ to the right of the $12$ vectors and then the diagonal of that former identity matrix will be my coefficients?

Here are the $12$ vectors:

$$v_1 = (0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0)$$
$$v_2 = (0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$v_3 = (1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)$$
$$v_4 = (0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$v_5 = (1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)$$
$$v_6 = (1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)$$
$$v_7 = (0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$v_8 = (0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$v_9 = (1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)$$
$$v_{10} = (1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)$$
$$v_{11} = (0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$v_{12} = (1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)$$

Comment: Why specifically do you *need* to find such a linear combination?  We know a linear combination will exist by dimension arguments.  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: If you want to understand the theory, then why not work with five length 4 vectors.  Actually performing the arithmetic by hand for your example will be incredibly tedious and does not help improve understanding any more than a much smaller more manageable example would.  If it really is necessary for some reason to finish *this* example, consider either just sucking it up and performing your row reduction as suggested by extending the number of columns so you have an identity matrix on the right... and god help you avoid making arithmetic or transcription mistakes... or write computer code

Comment: @JMoravitz factorization of a number using congruences of 2 different squares $\mod n$. You can see my post before this one for some context

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I’ve messed up several times, and ChatGPT’s (the only thing I could find for such a large matrix) answer wasn’t correct. I’ve spent hours on this one problem, mostly because of writing and reducing giant matrices

Comment: ChatGPT knows nothing about math.  It is a parrot who people blindly think has the ability to think who happens to be able to repeat more words than the average parrot but has less ability to think and reason.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I wasn’t surprised when it was wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149977/discussion-between-cotton-headed-ninnymuggins-and-jmoravitz).

Comment: @JMoravitz just to confirm, will extending the matrix with an identity matrix and reducing give me the correct coefficients assuming I don’t mess up?

Comment: Form the matrix whose columns are your $12$ vectors. Do elementary row operations (doing all the arithmetic modulo $2$, which should make life a lot easier) to bring it to reduced row echelon form. In that form, it's easy to find a vector in the nullspace , and a vector in the nullspace of the reduced matrix will also be in the nullspace of the riginal matrix, so the entries of that vector will be the coefficients you are looking for. If you don't get it, try doing it for the vectors $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and $(3,7)$, but working over the reals instead of modulo $2$.

Comment: Some nested for loops give the following solutions, not counting the trivial solution: 000010110001
001000000100
001010110101
010100010010
010110100011
011100010110
011110100111
100100001100
100110111101
101100001000
101110111001
110000011110
110010101111
111000011010
111010101011

Comment: Threw the dirty javascript code into the chatroom

Comment: @GerryMyerson JMoravitz coded to find a solution, but that is helpful as well. The null space in your small example should be $(-5,1,1)t$, so if I found this for my vectors, I'd have the solution then also.

Comment: @JMoravitz Interestingly, you obtain $15=2^4-1$ vectors which are the different sums that can be formed with the four basis vectors obtained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, @Gerry Myerson is right to say that it is a kernel issue. Here is why :

$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots a_nv_n=0 \ \iff $$

$$\pmatrix{| & | & \cdots & | \\ v_1&v_2& \cdots & v_n\\| & | & \cdots & | }\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\ \cdots\\a_n}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\ \cdots\\0}$$

The computation of a basis of the kernel can be easily done by the following SAGE program :

> ```
> B = MatrixSpace(GF(2),12,11);
> # B = space of 12 x 11 boolean matrices
> # Notation GF() = Galois Field
> M = B.matrix([
> [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],#v1
> [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],#v2
> [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],#v3
> [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#v4
> [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],#v5
> [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],#v6
> [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#v7
> [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],#v8
> [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],#v9
> [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],#v10
> [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],#v11
> [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0] #v12
> ]);
> K = M.kernel();K
> ```

It provides (instantly !) the following answer about a basis of the kernel :

"Vector space of degree 12 and dimension 4 over Finite Field of size 2"

"Basis matrix:"

> ```
> [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
> [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
> [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
> [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
> ```

What is the meaning of this answer ? That any of the four lines $[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{12}]$ gives a list of coefficients of a null combination $\sum a_kv_k=0$.

For example, the first line gives :

$$v_1+v_4+v_9+v_{10}=0$$

The third line : $v_3+v_{10}=0$ attracts our attention on the fact that $v_3$ and $v_{10}$ are identical...

Of course, these are "basic" null linear relationships. Any of the $2^4-1$ combinations of those yield also null linear relationships (these have been given in a comment by @JMoravitz, obtained by a different method).

It is to be noted that the kernel in SAGE is a **left** kernel (i.e., the kernel of the transposed matrix), but this is exactly what we need here.

**Remark :** it is very easy to use SAGE : just call https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ : a window is opened, type your program in it and press the button "Evaluate".